# How to completely remove youtube-dl from mac?

Tags: macos, file, uninstallation, removeall, youtube-dl

I installed youtube-dl with brew but it **wasn't working**... It kept saying connection refused.  So, I tried to reinstall in using the curl command at - https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl

```
sudo curl -L https://yt-dl.org/downloads/latest/youtube-dl -o /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
```

Still didn't work...  I tried uninstalling it like I did the first time with

```
brew remove youtube-dl
```

But that's obviously not working cause I didn't install it the second time with brew.  I just want to remove it now.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Let analyse the command you install:

```
sudo curl -L https://yt-dl.org/downloads/latest/youtube-dl -o /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
```

We can see the youtube-dl is install in our system path:

```
/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
```

So, in here we can remove the path directly.

```
$rm -rf /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
```

Maybe its not done yet, I used the command find if any remain path.

```
$sudo find / -name youtube-dl
```

After a few minutes waiting...There is no more remain youtube-dl in my mac. Cong!

Comment: If anyone wishes to locate the path of youtube-dl, then try:

$which youtube-dl